# In python3 ,after install twisteed, when import twisted it shows"ImportError: No module named 'twisted' "

Tags: python, ubuntu, twisted, python-3.4

I install the ubuntu 14.04LTS as a virtual machine, it has already install the python2.7 et python3.4 in the machine.
After that I use the command`sudo apt-get install python-twisted` to install the framework twisted, I can use `import twisted` in python 2.7 but I can't use this same command `import twisted` in python 3.4. It shows

```
>>> import twisted
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'twisted'
```

I have try many way to install the twisted, like

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
Sudo apt-get install python-dev
Sudo easy_install twisted
```

or

```
sudo pip install twisted
```

even download the pack`tar xjf Twisted-13.1.0.tar.bz2`and `tar xzf zope.interface-3.6.1.tar.gz` than run`python setup.py install`

However,unfortunately, these don't work.
Does anybody knows how to solute this problem? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because all of these libraries are installing to Python 2.7's libraries.

To install to Python 3, use `pip3`, not `pip`:

```
sudo pip3 install twisted
```

---

To understand why this happened to you, note that Ubuntu symlinks `python` to the `python2.7` executable and `python3` to `python3.4`.

From what I understand, packages such as these on `apt-get` internally call `python` during installation rather than `python3`. Hence why nothing gets installed to Python 3.4 in those cases.

The safe alternative is always to use `pip` for Python installation. `pip3` is symlinked to the version of `pip` that services only Python 3.4, so always call that for Python 3 packages.

An even better solution is to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to isolate different Python and pip versions from each other. That way, when you enter a virtual environment, you can use `pip` without worrying about the symlinked version.